# How to get a emoji by name, not ID and add it to the message? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know the name of emoji from printing `\emoji` in discord, but how to get the emoji that can be added to a message?

I would use ID and `bot.get_emoji`, but when I try to copy ID by Right click->Copy ID, the copied ID is an ID of a message with the emoji.

```
await msg2.add_reaction(":bookmark_tabs:")
```

I also tried to do that by `discord.utils.get()` but that caused an error

```
await msg2.add_reaction(discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name = "bookmark_tabs"))
await msg2.add_reaction(discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name = ":bookmark_tabs:"))
await msg2.add_reaction(discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name = "<bookmark_tabs:>"))
await msg2.add_reaction(discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name = "<:bookmark_tabs:>"))
```

All of these cause the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plays\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\bot2.py", line 172, in on_raw_reaction_add
await msg2.add_reaction(discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name = "<bookmark_tabs:>"))
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", 
line 927, in add_reaction
emoji = self._emoji_reaction(emoji)
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", 
line 1014, in _emoji_reaction
raise InvalidArgument('emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not 
{.__class__.__name__}.'.format(emoji))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bookmark_tabs` it's not a custom emoji so `discord.utils.get` will always return `None`, you need to get the unicode for it. To get it simply `\:emoji:` send it and copy the message.

The unicode got `bookmark_tabs` is , to add a reaction with it:

```py
await message.add_reaction('')
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, how to do the same with custom emojis?

Comment: You can do the same, the output will be something like this `<emoji_name:981723981739871>`, but you can also get the emoji instance with `bot.get_emoji(emoji_id)`